# Pushing icon to the right of text in Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Using **Bootstrap 3.3.7**, I'm trying to create a `two-column` row with the following content and characteristics:

- Left column `(col-sm-9)` that contains text
- Right column `(col-sm-3)` that contains one horizontally and vertically centered image
- Non-full-height vertical divider in between those two **divs**

I am having trouble getting the entire row to display with a minimum of 980 pixels and created a fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Codewalker/zLshudhe/):

Originally, the `image div` container on the right was only as tall as the image itself, so I added the following code to force same heights, but that caused the `width` to be reduced to the `size` of the contents within each div:

```
[class*="ccol-"] {
float: none;
display: table-cell;
vertical-align: middle;
}
```

I was wondering how other Bootstrappers might code out a simple row with text on the left, a vertical divider, and an image on the right.

Comment: which version of bootstrap are you using?

Comment: Bootstrap version is 3.3.7. I'll add that to the original post.

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend `flexbox` to center vertically.

```css
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .previewWrapper .row {
    display: flex;
  }
  .previewWrapper .row > * {
    flex-grow: 1;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction:column;
    justify-content: center;
  }
}
```

[`Updated snippet`](https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/u49uee6v/). Don't forget to [`autoprefix`](https://autoprefixer.github.io/). Please note I made it `9-3`, as you requested in question. If you want to keep it `10-2`, [`here it is`](https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/u49uee6v/1/).

Comment: I've placed it inside the `@media` query and updated. Just refresh.

Comment: I added it so the image was centered. But you can get that by using `text-align:center` on `.ccol-right p`, and `display: inline-block` on `img`, I guess. [`Here it is`](https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/u49uee6v/).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the  `min-width attribute`? You could force a container to be a certain size or bigger by adding, for instance, `"min-width: 980px;"` to the relevant container.

Comment: That's quite not true, @user3120861.  Bootstrap uses `display:table` for a lot of tiny *"hacks"*, besides displaying tabular data, of course. @David, I suggest not using answers for of comments, even though you're not yet able to comment.